# How to include google custom search box in an React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-search

I would like to add a google custom search box in my site, which is created by using ReactJS. So the user can search content both within the site and on web.

The Google generated code is something like:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '013626029679071:ze3ta4';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Is there a way to add this into the React component? It keeps saying SyntaxError. I tried to create a component for the above code and use it in the React Component, but nothings shows up. Is this the right way to add a searchbar on React site? Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes of course... Wrap the html tag "gcse:search" inside a div in the render method, and trigger the code of the anonimous function in the method componentdidmount of the component, ok?

Comment: If this not works, you can use refs to replace the vanilla javascript access dom element. More info: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @chemitaxis thanks for the reply, but wrapping the html tag "gsce:search" is not working, because it has the error "Namespace tags are not supported. ReactJSX is not XML." have you done it this way before?

Comment: No, I did not... did you test dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Comment: I think is this moment you can't do it... your unique option is use this: dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Comment: yes! I just tested with the dangerouslySetInnerHTML. however, it does not work either. The searchBar displays in the html page. I can also load this html page with no error, but it shows nothing. There is also no error showing up in the console. I used the inspect element, the code is there with an "!" in front of them. Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry @Lisa, If you create a codepen I could check...

Comment: @chemitaxis sure. here is the code that i am working on:  http://codepen.io/sasscsssass/pen/EZKPPz  . However, not sure how you would check. thanks a lot though!

Comment: @Lisa Hi, did you manage to fix this problem. If so, would you like to share the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution for you without using dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Put your code in the componentDidMount block and append to the element with jQuery like so:

```
componentDidMount(){
const embedcode = `<script>
      (function() {
        var cx = '013626029654558379071:ze3tw4csia4';
        var gcse = document.createElement('script');
        gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
        gcse.async = true;
        gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
      })();
    </script>
    <gcse:search></gcse:search>`

  $('#gsearch').html(embedcode)
  }
```

And your DOM element:

```
<div id='gsearch'>
</div>
```

Still debugging some styling stuff, but this works!

Best,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

This perfectly works for me. Add a form element in your react and modify the snippet as shown below. react return. Add a form element tag try it. it works for me.

```
<form method = "get" title = "Search Form" action="https://cse.google.com/cse/publicurl">
 <div>
    <input type="text" id="q" name="q" title="Search this site" alt="Search Text" maxlength="256" />
    <input type="hidden" id="cx" name="cx" value="013626029654558379071:ze3tw4csia4" />
   <input type="image" id="searchSubmit" name="submit" src="https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/active-search-symbol_34148" alt="Go" title="Submit Search Query" />
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Incomplete answer, does not say how this gonna work in React.