# create-react-app (TypeScript) .babelrc throwIfNamespace=true setting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs, create-react-app

thought this would be simple but it's not.  I generated a simple app with the latest create-react-app.  Adding  a `<gcse:search>` tag and getting the following:

```
Namespace tags are not supported by default. React's JSX doesn't support namespace tags. You can turn on the 'throwIfNamespace' flag to bypass this warning.
  16 |         return (
  17 |             <div className="comptext">
> 18 |                 <gcse:search defaultToRefinement="mostly-center"></gcse:search>
     |                  ^
  19 |             </div>
  20 |         );
```

.babelrc is:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-react",
            {
                "throwIfNamespace": false
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I've tried multiple .babelrc configurations, "babel" key in package.json, even tried including .bablerc.js.  No change

I'd prefer to not eject this, if possible.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577801/how-to-include-google-custom-search-box-in-an-react-component) it seems to solve problem without eject.

Comment: Same problem. `.babelrc` file is parsed, but this flag is ignored. If namespace is in xml, namespace not supported error is shown while try to use svg.

Answer (score -3):

You need to set it as follow:

`` "throwIfNamespace"`: false in file `@babel/preset-react/index.js ``